# Excel Named Range Conditional Statement

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

In Excel, I'm trying to check if the completed date field in a named range is filled out and if it is then don't show this record in the overdue list when the overdue button is pressed
so I'm looking for less than today but can't figure out how to write the other part of the formula in the code???

here is what I am doing this is the Criteria Section of the Named Range
With Sheet2

```
        .Range("Q7").Value = ""
        .Range("R7").Value = ""
        .Range("S7").Value = ""
        .Range("T7").Value = ""
        .Range("U7").Value = ""
        .Range("V7").Value = ""
        .Range("S7").Value = Me.txtLookup
        .Range("T7").Value = Me.cboRegion
        .Range("U7").Value = Me.cboDepartment
        .Range("V7").Value = Me.cboTraining
        
        .Range("Q7").Value = "=""<=""&TODAY()"   i think it gos here? but not sure how to write it
        
     
End With
```

Thanks for any help or examples!

Comment: You don't appeat to be referring to a named range any where in the code/formula.

Comment: So Sorry, This is the Criteria area of the Named range right after this it runs the Filter to pull the data,

Comment: Do you mean you are setting up the criteria for an advanced filter?

Comment: Yes, I am setting up the criteria for the filter and I think this is where I check for  if another field has data in it, and if so skip it in the results just don't know how to write it in VBA (Sorry still new to this kind of thing)

Comment: My goal = I have a Completed Date field and a Due Date Field if the completed date field is blank and the due date is < then today to show up in the overdue list when the button is pressed.  that's what I'm trying to accomplish Sorry for the poor explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a field isn't blank the criteria would be <>"" and the code would look like this.

```
.Range("Q7").Value = = "<>""""
```

To check if a field is blank the criteria would be ="" and the code would look like this.

```
.Range("Q7").Value = = "=""""
```

Comment: I also need it to check if it is earlier than today date so how do i add this "=""<=""&TODAY()" and your fix together?

Comment: Hey Norie Thanks for your help here but I'm not sure I'm communicating what my issue is here Sorry. I tried to add your fix and it errored out?? Let me try this way I have an advanced filter I'm trying to figure out how to get it to check if there is a date in the completed field and to not add that record when it is checking for dates less than today in the due date field?  the training manager wants the due date left in there so every date less than today comes up on the list how do I filter it out to show only the ones that do not have a date in the completed field and are less than today?

Comment: So you want to return records that have the date field filled in and that date is before today? Or is it the the date is after today?

Comment: if there is a Date in the completed field and the Due date is less than today do not show up on the list i only want records that do not have a completed date in them and the due date is less than today

Comment: hi Norie, to answer your question no i do not want to see those records im trying to filter out those records :)

Comment: So you are trying to set the criteria for 2 different fields, completed and due date?

Comment: Norie!!! Thank you So much! You are a great helper you made me look back upon what I was doing and realized I Was trying to set the criteria for 2 fields! :) Brilliant Thanks!! It works perfectly :)